# Why when i compare "." === "." return false?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

I'm working with a PIN PAD vx820, if not read either the card returns '.'

I want to show a message to the user to swipe the card again, but when I try to compare "." === "."  return false.

Its my comparation.

```
 "." === "."
```

[image: Console]

https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/dauf97b9/

Comment: `"." === "."` is true when copied from your question text.

Comment: Your JSFiddle example on the other hand has zero width spaces.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/dauf97b9/

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space

Comment: You have several invisible characters at the end of the first string. You can "see" them if you place the cursor at the end of the string and press left arrow. You'll notice you have to press several times before the cursor moves.

Comment: how I can delete zero width spaces , or  how as I can compare string?